# Select from multiple tables in SQL Server in C#

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I want to write SQL query which select some columns from the first table and all columns from the second table.

`ID` is the PK in `table1` and `id` is the FK in `table2`.

Is this correct:

```
SELECT ID, table2.ALL
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.ID = table2.id 
WHERE table1.ID= x AND table1.Column3 = 'y'
```

Comment: Have you tried running the query and seeing what happens?

Comment: Exception happen: " Incorrect syntax near '.'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you have a column called `ALL` in `table2` or do you want to select all columns from `table2` ??

If you want all columns use `table2.*` instead:

```
SELECT table1.ID, table2.*
FROM table1 
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.ID = table2.id 
WHERE table1.ID= x AND table1.Column3 = 'y'
```

Also, since you have `ID` in both tables, you need to specify which one to select in your statement.

**Update:** if you don't want all columns from `table2`, then you need to explicitly specify the columns that you do want:

```
SELECT 
    t1.ID, 
    t2.column1, t2.column2, ....., t2.columnN
FROM table1 t1 
INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.ID = t2.id 
WHERE t1.ID= x AND t1.Column3 = 'y'
```

Comment: Mr.marc_s I don't want to choose the FK column in the table2, how can do it?

Comment: @H_wardak: if you want don't want to select everything from a table, you need to explicitly specify which columns you want

Comment: I need all columns except the FK. Is there another way?

Comment: @H_wardak: yes, that's fine - then you need to **explitly specify** all the columns - except the FK ...... there is no magic way to specify "everything but this one column" ....

Answer (score 3):

You can't use `table2.ALL`.  That will look for a column called "All" in table2.  You want to use `table2.*` instead.

```
SELECT table1.ID, table2.*
FROM   table1 INNER JOIN table2 on table1.ID = table2.id
WHERE  table1.ID = x AND table1.Column3 = 'y'
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of "ALL", use *:

```
SELECT t1.ID, t2.* FROM table1 as t1
INNER JOIN table2 as t2 
ON t1.ID = t2.id 
WHERE t1.ID = x 
AND t1.Column3 = 'y'
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this:

```
select t1.ID, t2.*
from table1 t1
inner join table2 t2 on table1.ID = table2.id
WHERE t1.ID=xxx AND t1.Column3 = 'y'
```

Replace `xxx` by the `ID` that you want.